# "Standard first term" of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

A (not so interesting) question. Just to get good practices. When a series is considered in English, is the first term usually $a_0$ or $a_1$?

Comment: Yes, $a_0$ or $a_1$... .

Comment: ... and then what about the same question for a sequence...

Comment: Books (except by strange mathematicians) begin with Chapter 1, not Chapter 0.

Comment: I would think both, depending on context.

Comment: This depends on context and convenience. For instance, we often deal with trigonometric or power series which begin with a constant term. In this case a subscript $0$ is rather natural to avoid some annoying shifting in the summand. Barring something convenient to this effect, I usually see sequences and series starting with $1$.

Comment: The fist index is usually the firs element of $\mathbb N$ :)

Comment: I know it is a silly question! I raised it because if you start at $0$ then you cannot speak accurately of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ or $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ :-(.

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx I think it depends on context. Clearly, for $\sum\frac1n$, you can't start it at $0$. Generally, though, people would write $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ or $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}\frac1n$ to get rid of ambiguity. (Also, I have a book whose author uses the convention that $\sum\limits_n$ is to mean $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty$. He said so explicitly in the text.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good practice is to choose the first index that fits the task at hand. Sometimes it's $0$, like for Taylor series. Sometimes it's $1$, like for harmonic series. Sometimes it's $2$, like for $\sum \frac{1}{n\ln n}$.

Comment: I'm afraid by the series $\sum \frac {1}{n \ln n \ln (n-1)}$ :-)

Comment: There are  worse ones: $\sum\frac{1}{n\ln n\ln\ln n\ln \ln \ln n}$, etc